# Powershell: Possible to "expose" a variable created/updated in a script to the interactive session "above" the script?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2019

The title may be a little cryptic, so let me lay out the use case I have in mind:

I've written a powershell script that passes through all the windows logs, using:

```
$logs=get-winevent -listlog * | where {$_.RecordCount -gt 0} | Sort -property LogName
```

Then subsequently iterating through all the $logs, gathering up any/all events that are level "Error" or higher, and reporting on them all in a brief summary format that includes the containing log, event record id, event id, timestamp, severity, and message.

It would be "very handy" to be able to run that script interactively in a powershell session and have it gather up all those events into a hastable, perhaps keyed by the event recordid, such that I then could at my leisure choose to drill down into individual events for further exploration using various interactive commends as may suit my needs, all from inside the same powershell session from which I ran the script.

Problem is, I don't know if it's possible to create/update a hashtable (or other variable) inside a powershell script in such a way that makes it "visible" to the interactive powershell session I used to run the script.  Is that possible?  If so, how?

TIA
Rob

Comment: i think what you want is a 'synchronized' variable. take a look at this ... Sharing Variables and Live Objects Between PowerShell Runspaces | Learn Powershell | Achieve More — https://learn-powershell.net/2013/04/19/sharing-variables-and-live-objects-between-powershell-runspaces/

Comment: I was able to make that work.  Cool!  I had to declare and intialize the variable 'outside' in the session before invoking the script, via  

$stuff=[hashtable]::Synchronized(@{}) 

And then pass it into the script as a parm, but that was simple to do and it worked.  Afterwards I was able to reference specific event records in the hashtable interactively by using something like:

$stuff[[Int64]'nnnnn'] | fl *   (where nnnnn is a specific event record id)

to delve into the details of a specific instance.

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of trying to push a variable out of the script into the caller's scope, it might make more sense to let the script output the data you want to the pipeline. If you still want your summary as an option, you could add a `[switch]` param to the script that you can use to optionally output the summary or the data.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, but embedding the code in the script wouldn't accomplish what I want to do.  The whole point of this is that I don't know in advance what information I might want to extract from a particular event.  It depends on what the event itself is about.  I want the flexibility of having the whole event record available to me as an element in a hashtable so that I'm free to interactively examine it.

Comment: @BearGFR - you are most welcome! glad to have helped somewhat ... [*grin*]